# To skateboard vs to go skateboarding

Tags: grammar, verbs

Which of the sentences is correct?

1. I go skateboarding every week.
2. I skateboarded last Sunday.
3. I went skateboarding last Sunday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All are technically correct, but with differing contextual uses. Think of 'I went swimming' versus 'I swam', and usage tends to follow the same pattern. If it was a very specific swim e.g. 'I swam from one end of the pool to the other', then that is the form. You can also say 'I swam on Wednesday'but it would be more common to say 'I went swimming on Wed'.